# Declaring a class and subclass in two different files in python

Tags: python, class, import, subclass

I have two files, one declaring a superclass which involves a method involving a subclass, and the other defining the subclass.

File1:

```
from file2 import subclass

class superclass:
    def __init__(self):
        "Stuff"

    def method(self):
        temp = subclass()
        "Stuff"
```

File2:

```
from file1 import superclass

class subclass(superclass):
    def __init__(self):
        "Stuff"
```

When I run file1's code I get an error inside file2 that superclass is not defined.  This is because I import file2 before defining the superclass.

However if I import file2 after defining superclass I get an error in file1 saying the subclass is not defined.  This is because I use a subclass instance in the method.

One solution to this problem is to have both superclass and subclass declarations in a single file, but I am wondering if there is a way to have them declared in different files.

Comment: You can't have circular imports like this. You can't file file1 import file1, and file2 import file1. Why must file2 import file1?

Comment: @Bryan Oakley Doesn't the subclass need the superclass defined before you can declare the subclass?

Comment: Yes, it does. You must define a superclass before defining a subclass

Comment: That is why, as far as I know, though maybe there is another possibility and hence why I'm asking this question, file2 must first import file1.

Comment: It's highly unusual to have a superclass have an instance of a subclass as part of its data. There are probably better ways to design your object hierarchy. That's like saying a dog is a mammal, and part of a mammal definition is that it has a dog. Perhaps if you can explain why you need this unusual structure we can solve the real problem you're facing instead of finding a workaround to your workaround.

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: I will try to explain what I am doing:

I am as an exercise to learn Python making a code generator for a game (Starcraft broodwar).  In this game there are a limited number of integer variables (I think 1200).

If in my code I use one of these variables in a section of code and once this section of code is over it is set to zero, I want to be able to use this 'temporary integer' again in a later section of code.

Comment: However, there are other integers of course which I want to use for one a single thing (e.g. player level).

Thus, here is how my python code is structured:  I have two 1200 - sized boolian arrays with everything set to true initially, and a 1200 - sized array with each index containing the name of one of the 1200 integers allowed in the game.  When I declare a superclass instance it searches through the first boolian array and if it comes across a True index it sets that index to false in both boolian arrays.

Comment: Then when I use this superclass in code, e.g. like Trigger( If(superclass == 5) then (display_text("integer is 5") ), it will use whatever slot it was assigned to's integer-name from the 1200 sized array of integer names. in the game's code that my program generates.

Comment: Now as for the difference between the superclass and the subclasses, the superclass is for those integers which are used for a single thing, e.g. player level, and the subclass is for integers which are used in blocks of code but are set to 0 afterwards.

Comment: The subclass things can thus be freed up from their slot so that another subclass instance can take that same slot later.

Comment: So when the subclasses are declared it searches through the second 1200 boolian array for the first True index and sets that index of both boolian arrays to False.  This difference from the way the superclass searches through the first boolian array and the subclass searches through the second is important.  It is important because when I clear up the slot that a subclass is taking I only set to True the second boolian arrays slot.  This means that the next time I declare a superclass it will skip over that slot, but the next time I declare a subclass it will take that same slot.

Comment: This is needed because if a superclass integer were to take up the slot that a subclass integer took previously, it would be set to 0 in the block of code that the subclass integer was used for and thus for example it would constantly set the player level to 0, which would break everything in the game of course.

Comment: Anyway, there are methods you can do with the superclass integers which involve using other 'temporary' (subclass) integers which are set to 0 afterwards, which is why I need subclass instances in the superclass methods.

Comment: I doubt that this information will be of use to anyone but whatever, I guess I would be happy to be surprised.

Comment: I am curious - I tried to ask this question before and I got similar responses like "Why do you really want to do this."  I feel as though it's not that crazy of a thing to do though.  If you declare an object and one of its subclasses has many uses, wouldn't it be possible for one of those subclass uses to be useful in one of the superclass' methods?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is easy to understand if you look at how Python loads modules:

1. You run `python file2.py`.
2. Python loads `file2.py` and starts to execute it.
3. Python parses `from file1 import superclass`.
4. Python loads `file1.py` and starts to execute it.
5. Python parses `from file2 import subclass`.
6. As `file2` is already loaded, Python tries to access `file2.subclass`.
7. Python didn't yet parse the class statement, so `subclass` doesn't exist yet. This causes the `ImportError`.

Python can handle circular dependencies as long the classes are already parsed when the second import happens. There are two ways to get that:

1) import `file2` in the method itself.

```
class superclass:
    def __init__(self):
        "Stuff"

    def method(self):
        from file2 import subclass
        temp = subclass()
        "Stuff"
```

This causes the import to happen when `method` is called for the first time and not while importing/loading `file1`.
The downside is that there is some runtime overhead every time `method` is called and that you must make sure that `method()` is only called **after** the import of `file1` was completed.

2) import `file2` at the end of `file1` without using `from import`.

```
class superclass:
    def __init__(self):
        "Stuff"

    def method(self):
        temp = file1.subclass()
        "Stuff"

import file2
```

This way the circular import of `file2` happens when `superclass` already exists in the namespace of `file1`. At that time the namespace of `file2` is incomplete (`file2.subclass` doesn't exist yet, so `from file2 import subclass` would fail) but as long as `method` is never called before the imports succeeded, it works. The downside is that you need to keep track of which import statements need to be at the bottom of the file and which need to be at the top. Any error will cause `ImportErrors` that can be hard to track if your module hierarchy gets more complex.

That said, you should really rework your class hierarchy. Circular imports are (as I explained above) very fragile and should generally be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

Get `temp` from a method and override that method in the subclass.

```
class superclass:
    def get_temp(self):
        return 'a superclass temp'

    def method(self):
        temp = self.get_temp()
        print(type(self).__name__, repr(temp))

class subclass(superclass):
    def get_temp(self):
        return 'a subclass temp'


superclass().method()
subclass().method()
```

Output:

```
superclass 'a superclass temp'
subclass 'a subclass temp'
```

If you need `method()` to be different in `subclass` or perhaps do some work before or after `superclass.method()`, use the [super](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/) keyword.

Comment: I need exactly an instance of the subclass inside the superclass method though.  Doing it this way, if i do superclass.method() that method won't internally use a subclass instance.

Comment: `self` is an instance of `subclass` when called via `subclass().method()`

Comment: or if you need a brand new instance of `subclass`, you could do this: `instance = type(self)()`

Answer (score 0):

You can include the following line into your file2:

```
if superclass in locals(): print pass
else: 'Please define superclass'
```

Like this:

File2:

```
from file1 import superclass

class subclass(superclass):
    if superclass in locals(): pass
    else: print 'Please define superclass'
    def __init__(self):
        "Stuff"
```

Now try to run the file1 NOT file2. It will prompt 'Please define superclass'. But the subclass has been registered. Once you run something like:

```
x = superclass()
```

The subclass becomes workable.

Comment: Did the addition of two lines work or did you get a different solution. If you got a different solution, please share with us. 
Thanks :)