# Importing main class file to the child class file in Python

Tags: python, oop, package, python-module

So, basically, I have a folder called "Material" with two files in it: "Material.py" and "ElasticMaterial.py". Also, I have classes in each of the files called Material and ElasticMaterial respectively. Also, ElasticMaterial is a subclass of Material, hence, its class definition is:

```
class ElasticMaterial(Material):
    def __init__(self,StressState):

        self.StressState = StressState
        if self.StressState=='threed':
            self.lv=6  #lv is length of stress and strain vectors
        else:
            self.lv=4
```

If I am importing Material class as any of the following options:

```
import Material.Material

from Material.Material import Material

from . import Material
```

I am getting the error: "module.**init**() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)"

Also, can anyone suggest any good course on Python OOP and Packages? I am using Python 3.6.

P.S. I am trying to package my software such that each class is contained in its individual file.
Adding Code from Material.py file

```
import numpy as np
from Material.ElasticMaterial import ElasticMaterial
class Material(object):

    def newMaterial(matPhysLaw, stressState):
        if (matPhysLaw=="elastic"):

            return ElasticMaterial(stressState)
```

Comment: From your post it seems like the problem is in Material, so why you show us the code from ElasticMaterial?

Comment: I added the code from Material.py file too.

Comment: You're trying a circular reference (do you see that?).

Read [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42934799/declaring-a-class-and-subclass-in-two-different-files-in-python) for discussion and alternatives.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah further research showed me that.